# SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 with pictures

Tags: sql, sql-server, tcp, udp, portforwarding

I have this problem but I digged everywhere on solution, I tried almost everything. I have a static IP from my ISP and I try to connect Sql Server 2012 via internet.

First I tuned my router for port forwarding (TCP: 1433 and UDP: 1434, IP for TURAN: 192.168.1.27):

[image]

Second I tuned SQL Server Configuration:

[image]

Third I tuned Protocols for SQLEXPRESS:

[image]

Then I tuned my Windows Firewall:

[image]
[image]

Then I checked if ports is open via portqry:

[image]

After all, I am able to connect SQLEXPRESS like this:

[image]

But Not like that: (That is what I need to connect remotely, XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX means my static IP from my ISP)

[image]

Could you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved. Correct Server Name should be "tcp:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX\SQLEXPRESS".. I connected successfully. Thank you all.